# How to add an UNIQUE field to existing table with data for my table using mySQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, field, unique, alter

i`d like to add new unique field to my table but when i run command like

```
ALTER TABLE b_iblock_element ADD `XML_ID_UNIQUE` INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AFTER `XML_ID`
```

I have an error

> Duplicate entry '0' for key 'XML_ID_UNIQUE'!

How can I ignore this error?
Maybe there`re another commands in mySQL?

Comment: First add the column. Then fix the uniqueness. Finally add unique constraint.

Comment: is 0 a valid value for XML_ID_UNIQUE ?

If not, then alter table to allow NULL Values in XML_ID_UNIQUE

and before marking unique, replace all 0 with NULL

Update b_iblock_element set XML_ID_UNIQUE = NULL WHERE XML_ID_UNIQUE = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have data in the table, you need to do this in three steps:

```
-- add the column, with no unique constraint
ALTER TABLE b_iblock_element
    ADD `XML_ID_UNIQUE` INT NOT NULL AFTER `XML_ID`;

-- assign the values in the column some unique values
UPDATE b_iblock_element
    SET XML_ID_UNIQUE = <something unique>;

-- add in the unique constraint
ALTER TABLE b_iblock_element ADD CONSTRAINT unq_XML_ID_UNIQUE UNIQUE (b_iblock_element);
```

`<something unique>` could be assigned as:

```
UPDATE b_iblock_element CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT @rn := 0) params
    SET XML_ID_UNIQUE = (@rn := @rn + 1);
```

But you might have some other way of assigning values.